# How can I change the content of a combo box based on the content of the previous one?

Tags: java, wicket

I have a page containing two combo boxes. I want to make them in a way that when I change the first combo box the content of the second combo box, which is got from database, is changed. How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way to perform this kind of operations is through AJAX. You can easily add an AJAX Behavior to the first `DropDownChoice` in order to populate/refresh the choices of the second `DropDownChoice`.

Let's say you are using `IModel`s to get the choices of both `DropDownChoice`s. The `IModel` that gets the choices for the second `DropDownChoice` would be using the first `DropDownChoice`'s ModelObject (because it is dependent).

```
private DropDownChoice ddcCountry;
private DropDownChoice ddcCity;
//...

IModel countriesModel = new LoadableDetachableModel(){
   @Override
   protected Object load() {
      return myService.getCountries();
   }
};
IModel citiesModel = new LoadableDetachableModel(){
   @Override
   protected Object load() {
      if (ddcCountry.getModelObject() != null){
          return myService.getCities(ddcCountry.getModelObject());
      }
      else { return new ArrayList(); }
   }
};
ddcCountry = new DropDownChoice("country", null, countriesModel);
ddcCity = new DropDownChoice("city", null, citiesModel);
```

You can attach an [`AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/ajax/form/AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior.html) to the first `DropDownChoice`. That will output an `onchange` HTML event handler on the `<select>` tag, such that it will update that `DropDownChoice`'s model object with the selected value, and then will call your Behavior's [`onUpdate()`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/ajax/form/AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior.html#onUpdate%28org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxRequestTarget%29). In the `onUpdate()` method, you will only have to add the second `DropDownChoice` to the [`AjaxRequestTarget`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxRequestTarget.html) to write it back through the ajax response with the updated options. Remember to use  [`setOutputMarkupId(true)`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#setOutputMarkupId%28boolean%29) on all components you'll be adding to the `AjaxRequestTarget`.

For instance, for 2 dependent selects with countries and cities:

```
ddcCity.setOutputMarkupId(true);
ddcCountry.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior(){
    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        // here, ddcCountry's ModelObject has been already updated.
        ddcCity.setModelObject(null); // clear selection 
        if (target != null) { 
            // Adding the ddc to the AjaxRequestTarget will write
            // it back to the ajax response with new options pulled 
            // from the choices model.
            target.addComponent(ddcCity);
        }
    }
}
```

In case you're not using `IModels` for your choices (i.e. using `List` objects in the constructors), you'd just need to get the new `List` in the `onUpdate` method, and set it to `ddcCity` with [`setChoices()`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/AbstractChoice.html). You can get the `Component` the Behavior is bounded to with the [`getComponent()`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/behavior/AbstractAjaxBehavior.html#getComponent%28%29) method.

```
protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    // here, ddcCountry's ModelObject has been already updated.
    List cities = myService.getCities(getComponent().getModelObject());
    ddcCity.setChoices(cities);
    ddcCity.setModelObject(null); // clear selection 
    if (target != null) { 
        target.addComponent(ddcCity);
    }
}
```

In case you want to support users without javascript, you should add a submit button (maybe in a `<noscript>` tag?) with default from processing disabled, and perform that same logic in the button's `onSubmit`.

For additional reference, see this [DropDownChoice Examples](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/dropdownchoice-examples.html) Wicket wiki page, you might find the "Ajax" section interesting.

Comment: Thank you very much for the complete answer, I am being a fan of Wicket! :-)

Comment: @NoushinKhaki Glad this was useful :-) In this example, maybe having the `DropDownChoices` as `private` members is not the best choice. Additionally, you should call `detach()` on each of them on your `Page`/`Component` `detach()`, in order to detach the choices `LoadableDetachableModel`s and avoid having gettnig them serialized in the PageMap.